# How to run windows phone 8 emulator without visual studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Is there anything like ' Android SDK Manager ' for windows to run windows phone 8 emulator? Or is it possible to run it only by using visual studio ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by run their execution file :

```
step 1 - Use Win + R

step 2 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.1\XDE.exe"

or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0\XDE.exe"
```

which emulator you want run just changed it to 8.0/8.1

Comment: As I am trying to run the emulator in an amazon instance( virtual machine ) it is showing an error ( even after enabling Hyper V). I am not able to start a virtual machine inside it using Hyper V.

Comment: I enabled Hyper V. But not able to start a virtual machine. I am now trying to do the same on a physical machine( not instance ).

Comment: Hello.It did not work. I am getting the following error.
"The windows phone emulator cant find virtual machine with the name default Windows phone emulator. You are missing the -vhd parameter which is required to create a virtual machine."